# Flask API crashes when dataset is too large and stops serving requests

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask, tornado

I've a tornado server running in front of flask. Every time a request for a big dataset comes in, the API crashes and stops serving results.

This is my tornado file:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from trackyApi import app
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler

tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options={
        "certfile": "certificate.crt",
        "keyfile": "keyfile-decrypted.key",
    })
    http_server.listen(5000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And this is my flask file snippet:

```
class Result(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('start', type = str)
        parser.add_argument('end', type = str)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM myview
        WHERE [CreatedDate] BETWEEN ? AND ?
        ORDER BY [CreatedDate] DESC
                """

        connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        execute_with_retry(cursor, query, [args['start'], args['end']])

        json_dict = []

        for i in cursor.fetchall():
            res = {
            'TicketId':i[0], 'CreatedDate':str(i[1]), etc...
            }

            json_dict.append(res)

        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

        return jsonify(results=json_dict)
```

Javascript ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: api_url + 'Result',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,

            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa( + ":" + )
            },

            data: {start: start_date, end: end_date},
            success: function(result) {
                data = result.results;
                console.log(result.results[0]);
            }
         });
```

My view in SQL database is fairly complicated with inner joins from multiple tables. I'm not sure if that is the problem.

The API works just fine if my date range is last 3 days. But if I search for a month timeframe, API stops working for any requests thereafter.

I get this error on postman after every request made once an extra large date range is input:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to either:

A. Make API more robust so it also serves large dataset? (We're talking about ~1600 rows here)

OR B. Have some logic in place inside Flask API file which truncates result but serves regardless of the time period.

Is the problem with my flask API, or database, or Tornado server, or Javascript file calling the API?

Please help! Thanks.